# How to run my macro Automatic with any excel file that lands in my folder

Tags: excel, macros

I need help with an automation process , I have managed to create a macro that helps me out a lot but I also need to find a way to automate my macro to run automatic as soon as an excel file lands on my folder directory:

So the process will look like this:

1. Start
2. Excel files lands on my folder every 20min
3. I open excel file
4. Run my macro
5. Save and exit excel file
6. Move saved excel file into a different folder
7. End

What do I need to use in order to automate this process?
•   Vbscript
•   Cmd
•   .bat
•   Vba
•   Javascript

Your help will mean a lot towards this , thank you

Comment: If you have good programming skills, I would suggest to write a nodejs application using javascript

Comment: You could use `VBScript`, `VBA`, in fact most languages to achieve this...

Comment: where has this question been asked and answered? @Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: @Mohammed The link is right at the top of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is vbs code. It monitors a folder for a new file. Based on MS's Web Site code. `WITHIN 10` means every 10 secs check.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    filename = Split(objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent,"=")
    Set xlsfile = GetObject(filename(1))
Loop
```